# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion

My [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/86963/13815) to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86850) was deleted.  Why?

The question was about a team that uses color-coded source code to keep track of what needs to be done, but now they have a color-blind team member, and want to know what to do.  For anyone who can't read it, my answer was:

> Well, you could do what the rest of the world does and use an [issue tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems), along with comments in the code

This is a serious answer - there is no need to use a convoluted color-based system to solve a problem that has already been solved.  Apparently a lot of people agreed with me, since it was the third most-upvoted answer.

Yet, it was recently deleted.  Why?

Comment: I like your suggestion, it would make a good answer if you flesh it out to avoid the reason it was deleted, as outlined by Yannis in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

maple_shaft [added a post notice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/86850/revisions) at the same time he deleted your answer:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

My guess is that your answer was the reason for the post notice, as it reads more like a comment. What's missing for it to stand as an answer is a line or two explaining how using an issue tracker would solve the specific problem presented in the question. "Use an issue tracker" is good advice, but useless to someone who has no idea what an issue tracker is.

If you expand your answer, please flag it for moderation attention so we can undelete it.